# Infinitive governed by a verb

Tags: prépositions, infinitif, constructions, de, à

> Il veut le faire. Il réussit à le faire. Il essaya de le faire.

Are there any general rules that dictate which (governing) verbs require a plain infinitive, which an infinitive with the preposition à and which an infinitive with the preposition de, or it is just a matter of familiarity and learning?

In general, how do French children learn the different cases in school? Are they provided with a consolidated list or is teaching based on the use of mnemonics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quelques règles... tant... il me plait **de** penser qu'il y en a... ;)
Hmmm... tout en... me plaisant **à** penser... la même chose...

A/ **Pas de préposition** avec les verbes de mouvement (1) et les verbes qui expriment une opinion (2), une nécessité (3), une volonté (4).

- (1) *Je **vais** partir*
- (2) *Je **préfère** m'en aller, je pense réussir*
- (3) *Il **faut** partir*
- (4) *Je **veux** partir*

B/ Tous les autres verbes demanderont une préposition :

- **de** pour les verbes utilisés en tant que transitifs directs

*J'arrête + COD => J'arrête de t'embêter !*

- **à** pour les verbes utilisés en tant que transitifs indirects

*Je t'aide + COI => Je t'aide **à** apprendre. Je renonce **à** t'apprendre*

Comment: Merci. I would also add verbs of seeing, hearing, feeling to those of A/. In addition, can you elaborate more on B/? J'arrête de t'embêter ! Je renonce à t'apprendre, quelle est la différence?

Comment: Oui pour le seing / hearing / feeling. J'incluais tout cela dans *opinion* car après tout... le hearing/feeling/seing... c'est bien de l'opinion que c'est. ;)

Comment: Quant à la différence des B/, j'aurais aussi pu l'exprimer en te disant : Pose-toi la question sur ce que tu veux dire : Tu arrêtes QUOI (COD) ou tu arrêtes À QUOI (COI) ? Tu renonces QUOI (COD) ou tu renonces À QUOI (COI)

Comment: Comme partout ailleurs. Si on cherche une règle à un truc. Je veux dire une logique quoi... c'est dans la grammaire qu'il faut chercher. Dans les langues, seule la grammaire suit une logique.

Comment: Comment analyseriez-vous "il vient de partir", "il couraient à perdre haleine"?

Comment: @user168676 Il vient de partir means He has just left. Here venir de is used as an auxiliary verb in order to express the so-called passé récent.

Comment: @user168676 À perdre haleine est une locution adverbiale (expression figée) http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/13876/a-perdre-haleine/ À perdre haleine est nécessairement associé à un effort (courir...).

Comment: @aCOSwt Based on these rules how can we explain the difference between il demanda à sortir et il lui demanda de l'aider?

Comment: @dimitris! Pour ton explication relative au passé récent : ++ de ++ de brillant de... bravo!  de KUDOS ++ Dans mes bras Obélix! T'as tout compris!

Comment: @dimitris : Et oui aussi de ++ KUDOS... pour la locution adverbiale figée!! Bon... hé... à tous... si vous avez besoin de moi... adressez vous à dimitris! ;) Bravo encore!

Comment: @aCOSwt Je te remercie vivement pour les bonnes paroles:-)! FSE est comme une classe de français !

Comment: Dans quelle classe, on doit mettre *savoir*, *voir*, *imaginer*, *recommander* ?

Comment: @GAMPUB : Je... sais... te répondre... :-)  *Recommander* : Cas général. Transitif direct -> *Recommander de...* / *Savoir*, *je sais* exprime une opinion -> pas de préposition. Id pour *voir*

Comment: @aCOSwt Je n'ai pas compris ce commentaire-réponse... Qu'est-ce qui pourrait bien montrer que *savoir*, *voir* ou *imaginer* exprime une opinion plutôt qu'un état pour le premier et des perceptions pour les deux autres ?

Comment: @GAMPUB : Demande-toi à quel ordre de choses appartient le COD de ces verbes que tu cites (savoir/voir/imaginer). Il s'agit (en général) de prédicats. (A est tel que *blahblah*). On peut donc appeler cela des *jugements* mais... comme il sont souvent contestables... on se fait plus modeste : opinions!

Answer (score -1):

Your second choice is the right one I believe: through familiarisation by means of reading, essentially.

There is no "list learning" for that.

Comment: Non! Il existe tout de même quelques règles de base.

Comment: Assez surprenant, en disposez-vous d'une? Voudriez-vous, s'il vous plait, en citer une?

Comment: Voyez la réponse de @aCOSwt pour les règles de base.

Comment: @Dimitris 1) Pas un verbe de mouvement : « aller » n'exprime pas le mouvement parce que c'est un semi auxiliaire dans ce cas particulier. « Venir » est un semi auxiliaire dans « Je viens d'apprendre la nouvelle » (il faut « **de** ») ; dans « je viens voir », encore un semi auxiliaire, mais  pas de préposition. « aimer » n'entre dans aucune des 4 catégories mais on dit « Il aime courir. ». Une référence qui ajouterait des choses utiles à la réponse : https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/les-verbes-avec-la-preposition-de-ou-a-ou-sans-preposition-suivis-d-un-infinitif-88.php (1/2)

Comment: @Dimitris Beaucoup de verbes sont catalogués ; vous avez donc des listes que vous pouvez essayer de mémoriser. Cependant, comme je l'exprime dans ma réponse, elles sont tellement longues que pendant que vous les étudiez vous ne lisez rien, vous vous privez des contextes dans lesquels sont les verbes et c'est rebutant, vous n'apprenez pas bien, alors que si vous choisissez des lectures intéressantes et variées le processus d'assimilation est beaucoup plus effectif ; petit à petit vous aurez mémorisé une foule de verbes avec leur préposition. (2/2)