# Comment puis-je savoir quel - Should I use sais instead of savoir?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

The verb "Savoir" when it comes to `Je`. It is `sais`.

And according to this sentence:

```
Comment puis-je savoir quel...

How do I know when...
```

But here, I'm using `savoir`, and not `sais`. Why can this be done? I mean, this sentence is about `me` = `je`, should it not be then

```
Comment puis-je sais quel...
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one a verb follows another verb, the second one must be in infinitive form.

> Je peux savoir...=>Comment puis-je savoir...

[Note it is more to common to see *comment est-ce que je peux savoir*]

[Infinitive governed by a verb](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31329/infinitive-governed-by-a-verb)

Comment: When I talk inside forums, they never use "est-ce que".

Comment: @DanielMårtensson "Puis-je..." is quite formal so I would say that "Est-ce que je peux..." is more common. And what's even more common is simply saying "Je peux...? (that is, with rising intonation)". Whether my assertion is valid can be verified by a native.

Comment: @Dimitris It is. "Je peux... ?" is quite informal but ok in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is the same as in English. you would say

"How does he **know**?" and not "how does he **knows**?

The second verb is not related to the subject but to the first verb, so it takes the infinitive form whatever person is related.

Comment: I'm not sure this holds up, 'how does he know' would be translated as 'comment sait-il'. 'Does' is an auxiliary verb here, not a main verb.